# How to extract a part of a side of a regular polygon?

Tags: tikz-pgf, polygon

Is there a better way of drawing the following picture without the ab segment? I used the following code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5.5]
    \node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, minimum size=10cm, rounded corners, draw] at (0,0) {};
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Erase ab segment
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \draw[ultra thick, white](-.377,.787025) -- (.377,.787025);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \draw(.377,.787025)arc(276:90:.06);
  \draw(-.377,.787025)arc(-96:90:.06);
   \def\mypath{(-.06,-.98) -- (-.06,-.95) arc (180:0:.06cm) -- (.06,-.98)}
    \foreach \t in {0,120,240} {\draw   [rotate=\t] \mypath;}
\def\mypath{(0,.98) -- (0,.98) arc (90:55.5:.98cm)}% -- (0,0)}
\draw   [rotate=56.5] \mypath;
\def\mypath{(0,.98) -- (0,.98) arc (90:55.5:.98cm)}% -- (0,0)}
\draw   [rotate=-22] \mypath;
\def\mypath{(0,.98) -- (0,.98) arc (90:-23:.98cm)}% -- (0,0)}
\draw   [rotate=176.5] \mypath;
\def\mypath{(0,.98) -- (0,.98) arc (90:-23:.98cm)}% -- (0,0)}
\draw   [rotate=296.5] \mypath;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the node with a proper path. You know that the diameter of the circumcircle of the hexagon is 10cm unscaled (because nodes are not scaled when using the `scale` option). Thus, the scaled radius of the circumcircle of the hexagon is 5cm / 5.5.

You also know the coordinates where the two half circles at the top start and end. Thus, you can easily recreate the outline of the node shape using `\draw` with polar coordinates.

In the following code example, I simplified your code a bit and also updated it to current syntax.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5.5]
    % \node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, minimum size=10cm, rounded corners, draw] at (0,0) {};
    \draw[rounded corners] (-.377,.787025) -- (120:{5/5.5}) -- (180:{5/5.5}) -- (240:{5/5.5}) -- (300:{5/5.5}) -- (360:{5/5.5}) -- (60:{5/5.5}) -- (.377,.787025);
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Erase ab segment
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % \draw[ultra thick, white](-.377,.787025) -- (.377,.787025);
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \draw(.377,.787025) arc[start angle=276, end angle=90, radius=.06];
    \draw(-.377,.787025) arc[start angle=-96, end angle=90, radius=.06];
    \def\mypath{(-.06,-.98) -- (-.06,-.95) %
        arc[start angle=180, end angle=0, radius=.06] -- (.06,-.98)}
    \foreach \t in {0,120,240} {
        \draw[rotate=\t] \mypath;
    }
    \def\mypath{(0,.98) -- (0,.98) arc[start angle=90, end angle=55.5, radius=.98]}
    \draw[rotate=56.5] \mypath;
    \draw[rotate=-22] \mypath;
    \def\mypath{(0,.98) -- (0,.98) arc[start angle=90, end angle=-23, radius=.98cm]}
    \draw[rotate=176.5] \mypath;
    \draw[rotate=296.5] \mypath;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]